# Mongoose Could not connect to servers in My MongoDB Atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have just created an Atlus mongo db account which is based on Paris and added IP Access, now I'm trying to access it from the Mumbai server. but getting below error.

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/sbfasto/backendfortsmith.sbfasto.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:825:32)
    at /home/sbfasto/backendfortsmith.sbfasto.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:411:10
    at /home/sbfasto/backendfortsmith.sbfasto.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/sbfasto/backendfortsmith.sbfasto.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/sbfasto/backendfortsmith.sbfasto.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1285:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/sbfasto/backendfortsmith.sbfasto.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:410:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sbfasto/backendfortsmith.sbfasto.com/app.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-nbyh9mn-shard-00-00.6yz0ajv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-nbyh9mn-shard-00-01.6yz0ajv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-nbyh9mn-shard-00-02.6yz0ajv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-a81bt4-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

after this I added IP access  for any ip still getting same error. can anyone tell me the reason?

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://popcorn:<password>@fortsmith.6yz0ajv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(() => console.log('mongo connected')).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit removed

Comment: Is your IP whitelisted from your atlas cluster?